# Filter multiple columns in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, vba

> COLUMNS employee_id,  last_name,  first_name, reporting_to,   official_start_time,    employee_status,    dept_name

Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

```
Dim strSELECT As String = 
    "SELECT * FROM [TABLENAME]WHERE last_name LIKE '"     
    & tbxLastName.Text.ToString() 
    & "%' AND first_name LIKE'" & tbxFirstName.Text.ToString() & "%' AND reporting_to LIKE '" 
    & tbxReportingTo.Text 
    & "%' AND employee_status = '" 
    & cbxEmpStatus.Items(cbxEmpStatus.SelectedIndex) & "'AND dept_name ='" 
    & cbxDeptName.Items(cbxDeptName.SelectedIndex).ToString &"';"
End Sub
```

With the click of the button search I want to filter my data with input items.

---

The problem I am having is if I leave one textbox blank the query does not work any work around with that. Below I will put a sample code suggested by someone but I have no idea on how to implement it.

```
Public Function ReadRecords(ByVal strTblName As String,
    ByVal strColumns As String,
    ByVal strFilter As String,
    ByVal strSortOrder As String) As DataTable

    Dim dtRecords As New DataTable
    Dim strSQL As String

    If strColumns = String.Empty Then
        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + strTblName
    Else
        strSQL = "SELECT " & strColumns & " FROM " + strTblName
    End If

    If strFilter <> String.Empty Then
        strSQL = strSQL + " WHERE " + strFilter
    End If
    If strSortOrder <> String.Empty Then
        strSQL = strSQL + " ORDER BY " + strSortOrder
    End If

    dtRecords = ExecQuery(strSQL)
    Return dtRecords
End Function
```

Below I have a picture of a sample DB[Do not mind the column names in it] I want to be able to filter for example all the records containing IT as department and simultaneously also search for the first letter of the last name let's say W
so the output of my query should be the employee  100 William ETC...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A37B0.jpg)

Comment: Neither of the 2 language tags are correct and the correct one is missing?

Comment: This needs to be done using command/parameter objects, currently you have SQL Injection vulnerabilities

Answer (score 0):

Public Function ReadRecords(ByVal strTblName As String,
                            ByVal strColumns As String,
                            ByVal strFilter As String,
                            ByVal strSortOrder As String) As DataTable

```
Dim dtRecords As New DataTable
Dim strSQL As String

If strColumns = String.Empty Then
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + strTblName +" WHERE " 
Else
    strSQL = "SELECT " & strColumns & " FROM " + strTblName +" WHERE " 
End If

If strFilter <> String.Empty Then
    strSQL = strSQL + + strFilter
End If
If strSortOrder <> String.Empty Then
    strSQL = strSQL + strSortOrder
End If

dtRecords = ExecQuery(strSQL)
Return dtRecords
```

End Function

you have to add the WHERE Condition before if statement,
updated your code please test this.

Comment: It's just a code snippet sir. The error is I can not search the database using my original code which is the first one. The second code is just a guide if you know how to implement my first code in it.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use the `%` operator and the `LIKE` keyword if I'm not mistaken.
Your query should look like `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE columnName LIKE condition + %`